# Unable to pull changes from git repo

Tags: git, github, git-svn, smartgit, phpfog

I ve developed a php/Facebook app and I’ve hosted it over phpfog, the main functionality of the app is asking user for some information and then putting it csv format into a notepad file.

To access phpfog repository I am using a git-ui called Smart-Git 3, things are cool and fine as far as post changes are concerned.

But when I am trying to pull the changed made like updated and new entered information i am not getting it the .txt files remains the same and is not showing me the updated records added.

I am pretty confused with it as my whole app is completed an d people have entered info into it but I’m unable to retrieve that info.

Kindly help.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your situation. Are you trying to pull user-generated changes to text files from your repository? If so, does your application commit those changes to the repository?

Comment: Check SmartGit's Log and use Graph|Select Branches - "All Branches" there. Can you see the commits of other authors there? Are they in a different branch?

Comment: @Michael: Changes are made by my app by storing information it gathered through a form.

Comment: @Maven Are you explicitly calling commit when your form submits?

Comment: you mean from php code? no not really.

Answer (score 0):

PHP Fog uses git as a one-way versioning tool. This means changes made by your app such as cache, uploads, and your app generated csv file **will not** get checked into the PHP Fog git repo. You will not be able to pull the csv file.

You can install a file manager in order to download that csv file if needed: http://phpfm.sourceforge.net/